# Is it possible to set up job spec to return complex object for Chainlink Node Operator?

Tags: chainlink

For now, it is common to return a value with a basic type, like `ethbytes32`, what if we want to return a string result and its length over 256? Or could we return an object, like `dict`, array or so?

Answer (score 2):

With the current version of the Chainlink node, only results up to `bytes32` are supported. In future versions, there will be improvements around what can be returned. In the meantime, you can make multiple requests as a workaround